# Is there a tool to detect what technologies a website uses?

Tags: linux, tools, kali-linux, reconnaissance

I'm looking for the name of a tool I've used a long time ago, that for a given URL/website address would extract the technologies used for that site.
For example that the site is running Apache, using PHP 5.3, or IIS7 with asp.net, with vBulleting etc.

Does anyone remember what tool I'm referring to?
(P.S.: I know that "BuiltWith" has a service for this, I explicitly remember a tool in Kali Linux (or even back in BackTrack)

Comment: I would start with looking at the headers the webserver returns. this often yields the information you specify.

Comment: Software recommendations can be posted on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Any tool designed to automate web vulnerability assessment should be capable of this, though detections may not be 100% reliable.

Comment: If it was in BackTrack/Kali, you were probably using nmap or zenmap, which provides estimates of systems based on fingerprints found in the responses.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in an online tool `http://www.whatweb.net/` or an equivalent `whatweb` program in *nix. (`http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/whatweb`).

Answer (score 1):

Not the tool you're looking for but webappalyzer has chrome and firefox plugins which can give you information about websites you are visiting.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en

This sounds like it fits the description of what you're looking for.